# Reduce array objects by key and return a nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects.

```
let data = [
    {year: 2018, monthNumber: 0, rev: 40984, exp: 15525, profit: 25459}
    {year: 2018, monthNumber: 0, rev: 162457, exp: 53608, profit: 108849}
    {year: 2019, monthNumber: 0, rev: 8935, exp: 12514, profit: -3579}
    {year: 2019, monthNumber: 0, rev: 32354, exp: 11184, profit: 21170}
    {year: 2018, monthNumber: 1, rev: 30620, exp: 16974, profit: 13646}
    {year: 2018, monthNumber: 1, rev: 9050, exp: 12431, profit: -3381}
    {year: 2019, monthNumber: 1, rev: 9050, exp: 12522, profit: -3472}
    {year: 2019, monthNumber: 1, rev: 12265, exp: 12752, profit: -487}
    {year: 2018, monthNumber: 2, rev: 9955, exp: 12424, profit: -2469}
    {year: 2018, monthNumber: 2, rev: 13657, exp: 13424, profit: 233}
    {year: 2019, monthNumber: 2, rev: 9050, exp: 12410, profit: -3360}
    {year: 2019, monthNumber: 2, rev: 15045, exp: 13315, profit: 1730}
]
```

The goal is to first to dynamically SUM all the key values into one array depending on the year and monthNumber.

The original array is but a sample, there are multiple additional keys other than 'exp', 'profit', etc. I would like to make it dynamic and avoid mentioning every key.

```
[
    {year: 2018, monthNumber: 0, rev: 203441, exp: 69133, profit: 134308}
    {year: 2019, monthNumber: 0, rev: 41289, exp: 23698, profit: 17591}
    {year: 2018, monthNumber: 1, rev: 39670, exp: 29405, profit: 10265}
    {year: 2019, monthNumber: 1, rev: 21315, exp: 25274, profit: -3959}
    {year: 2018, monthNumber: 2, rev: 23612, exp: 25848, profit: -2236}
    {year: 2019, monthNumber: 2, rev: 24095, exp: 25725, profit: -1630}
]
```

and after that attain the below desired output:

```
{ 
    rev : {
        2019 : [203441, 39670, 23612],
        2018 : [41289, 21315, 24095],
    },
    exp : {
        2019 : [69133, 29405, 25848],
        2018 : [23698, 25274, 25725],
    },
    profit: {
        2019 : [134308, 10265, -2236],
        2018 : [17591, -3959, -1630],
    }
}
```

Comment: So what did you attempt?

Comment: FYI: Your output is actually wrong.

Comment: Honestly, everything I've tried is a got too complidated and came to dead ends, From reduce and then forEach. I hope you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: what is with `EBITDA` property?

Comment: `reduce` iterates a list structure processing a function upon each list-item, it does iterate. If one knows, that this function's first argument works best as an accumulating object if it also is the very return value of this function whilst this function's second argument is the list-item, one now can come up with a generic process that pretty much can reduce any listed data-structure. So what was your genric approach?

Comment: @NinaScholz adjusted

Comment: UPDATED : got a bit fixed up with the values of monthNumber

Comment: do you need now the intermediate result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a dynamic approach and take `year` and `monthNumber` out of the object for grouping.

Later create a `plain` array from the object.

```js
var data = [{ year: 2018, monthNumber: 0, rev: 40984, exp: 15525, profit: 25459 }, { year: 2018, monthNumber: 0, rev: 162457, exp: 53608, profit: 108849 }, { year: 2019, monthNumber: 0, rev: 8935, exp: 12514, profit: -3579 }, { year: 2019, monthNumber: 0, rev: 32354, exp: 11184, profit: 21170 }, { year: 2018, monthNumber: 1, rev: 30620, exp: 16974, profit: 13646 }, { year: 2018, monthNumber: 1, rev: 9050, exp: 12431, profit: -3381 }, { year: 2019, monthNumber: 1, rev: 9050, exp: 12522, profit: -3472 }, { year: 2019, monthNumber: 1, rev: 12265, exp: 12752, profit: -487 }, { year: 2018, monthNumber: 2, rev: 9955, exp: 12424, profit: -2469 }, { year: 2018, monthNumber: 2, rev: 13657, exp: 13424, profit: 233 }, { year: 2019, monthNumber: 2, rev: 9050, exp: 12410, profit: -3360 }, { year: 2019, monthNumber: 2, rev: 15045, exp: 13315, profit: 1730 }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { year, monthNumber, ...o }) => {
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => {
            r[k] = r[k] || {};
            r[k][year] = r[k][year] || [];
            r[k][year][monthNumber] = (r[k][year][monthNumber] || 0) + v;
        });
        return r;
    }, {}),
    plain = Object.entries(result).reduce((r, [k, years]) => {
        Object.entries(years).forEach(([year, array]) => array.forEach((v, monthNumber) => {
            var temp = r.find(q => q.year === year && q.monthNumber === monthNumber);
            if (!temp) r.push(temp = { year, monthNumber });
            temp[k] = v;
        }));
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
console.log(plain);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hello, in the above where can we include the summation of the values?

Comment: where do you want it?

Comment: I want to first sum the rev and exp and profit for each year and monthNumber

Comment: please add this information to the question in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce` and add them up. Edit, added the ability to not know what the keys are.

```js
let data = [
    {year: 2018, monthNumber: 0, rev: 40984, exp: 15525, profit: 25459},
    {year: 2018, monthNumber: 0, rev: 162457, exp: 53608, profit: 108849},
    {year: 2019, monthNumber: 0, rev: 8935, exp: 12514, profit: -3579},
    {year: 2019, monthNumber: 1, rev: 32354, exp: 11184, profit: 21170},
    {year: 2018, monthNumber: 1, rev: 30620, exp: 16974, EBITDA: 13646},
    {year: 2018, monthNumber: 1, rev: 9050, exp: 12431, profit: -3381},
    {year: 2019, monthNumber: 1, rev: 9050, exp: 12522, profit: -3472},
    {year: 2019, monthNumber: 2, rev: 12265, exp: 12752, profit: -487},
    {year: 2018, monthNumber: 2, rev: 9955, exp: 12424, profit: -2469},
    {year: 2018, monthNumber: 3, rev: 13657, exp: 13424, profit: 233},
    {year: 2019, monthNumber: 3, rev: 9050, exp: 12410, profit: -3360},
    {year: 2019, monthNumber: 3, rev: 15045, exp: 13315, profit: 1730}
]

const add = (obj, type, year, month, value) => {
  obj[type] = obj[type] || {}
  obj[type][year] = obj[type][year] || []
  obj[type][year][month] = (obj[type][year][month] || 0) + value
}

var result = data.reduce((obj, record) => {
    const {
      year,
      monthNumber,
    } = record
      const ignore = ['year', 'monthNumber']
      Object.keys(record).forEach(key => {
        if (!ignore.includes(key)){
          add(obj, key, year, monthNumber, record[key])
        }
      })
      
      return obj
    }, {}
);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = data.reduce(function(total, currentValue){
    let year = currentValue.year;
    let monthNumber = currentValue.monthNumber;
    if(!total.rev[year]){
        total.rev[year] = [];
        total.exp[year] = [];
        total.profit[year] = [];
    }
    if(!total.rev[year][monthNumber]){
        total.rev[year][monthNumber] = 0;
        total.exp[year][monthNumber] = 0;
        total.profit[year][monthNumber] = 0;
    }
    if(typeof currentValue.rev == "number") total.rev[year][monthNumber] += currentValue.rev;
    if(typeof currentValue.exp == "number") total.exp[year][monthNumber] += currentValue.exp;
    if(typeof currentValue.profit == "number") total.profit[year][monthNumber] += currentValue.profit;
    return total;
}, {
    rev : {},
    exp : {},
    profit : {}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can go through all the values and add depending on the year

```js
var _data=[{year:2018,monthNumber:0,rev:40984,exp:15525,profit:25459},{year:2018,monthNumber:0,rev:162457,exp:53608,profit:108849},{year:2019,monthNumber:0,rev:8935,exp:12514,profit:-3579},{year:2019,monthNumber:0,rev:32354,exp:11184,profit:21170},{year:2018,monthNumber:1,rev:30620,exp:16974,profit:13646},{year:2018,monthNumber:1,rev:9050,exp:12431,profit:-3381},{year:2019,monthNumber:1,rev:9050,exp:12522,profit:-3472},{year:2019,monthNumber:1,rev:12265,exp:12752,profit:-487},{year:2018,monthNumber:2,rev:9955,exp:12424,profit:-2469},{year:2018,monthNumber:2,rev:13657,exp:13424,profit:233},{year:2019,monthNumber:2,rev:9050,exp:12410,profit:-3360},{year:2019,monthNumber:2,rev:15045,exp:13315,profit:1730}];

var _desired = {rev:{},exp:{},profit:{}}
_data.forEach(key=>{
  if(!_desired.rev[key.year]){
    _desired.rev[key.year] = [];
  }
  if(!_desired.exp[key.year]){
    _desired.exp[key.year] = [];
  }
  if(!_desired.profit[key.year]){
    _desired.profit[key.year] = [];
  }
  _desired.rev[key.year].push(key.rev);
  _desired.exp[key.year].push(key.exp);
  _desired.profit[key.year].push(key.profit);
})
console.log(_desired);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, I don't know it will match to your purpose or not:

```js
let data = [
    {year: 2018, monthNumber: 0, rev: 40984, exp: 15525, profit: 25459},
    {year: 2018, monthNumber: 0, rev: 162457, exp: 53608, profit: 108849},
    {year: 2019, monthNumber: 0, rev: 8935, exp: 12514, profit: -3579},
    {year: 2019, monthNumber: 1, rev: 32354, exp: 11184, profit: 21170},
    {year: 2018, monthNumber: 1, rev: 30620, exp: 16974, EBITDA: 13646},
    {year: 2018, monthNumber: 1, rev: 9050, exp: 12431, profit: -3381},
    {year: 2019, monthNumber: 1, rev: 9050, exp: 12522, profit: -3472},
    {year: 2019, monthNumber: 2, rev: 12265, exp: 12752, profit: -487},
    {year: 2018, monthNumber: 2, rev: 9955, exp: 12424, profit: -2469},
    {year: 2018, monthNumber: 3, rev: 13657, exp: 13424, profit: 233},
    {year: 2019, monthNumber: 3, rev: 9050, exp: 12410, profit: -3360},
    {year: 2019, monthNumber: 3, rev: 15045, exp: 13315, profit: 1730}
]

var result={};

function simplearray(obj){
  //alert(obj.year);
  if(typeof result[obj.year]== "undefined")
  {
    result[obj.year]={};
  }
  if(typeof result[obj.year][obj.monthNumber]== "undefined")
  {
    result[obj.year][obj.monthNumber]={};
  }      

  if(typeof result[obj.year][obj.monthNumber]["rev"]== "undefined")
  {
    result[obj.year][obj.monthNumber]["rev"]=0;
    result[obj.year][obj.monthNumber]["exp"]=0;
    result[obj.year][obj.monthNumber]["profit"]=0;
  }      
  result[obj.year][obj.monthNumber]["rev"]+=obj.rev;
  result[obj.year][obj.monthNumber]["exp"]+=obj.exp;
  result[obj.year][obj.monthNumber]["profit"]+=obj.profit;
  
  
}

for (a=0;a<data.length;a++)
{
  simplearray(data[a]);
}   


console.log(result);
console.log(result[2018][2].rev);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Second way, if the monthNumber is indexed well:

```js
let data = [
    {year: 2018, monthNumber: 0, rev: 40984, exp: 15525, profit: 25459},
    {year: 2018, monthNumber: 0, rev: 162457, exp: 53608, profit: 108849},
    {year: 2019, monthNumber: 0, rev: 8935, exp: 12514, profit: -3579},
    {year: 2019, monthNumber: 0, rev: 32354, exp: 11184, profit: 21170},
    {year: 2018, monthNumber: 1, rev: 30620, exp: 16974, profit: 13646},
    {year: 2018, monthNumber: 1, rev: 9050, exp: 12431, profit: -3381},
    {year: 2019, monthNumber: 1, rev: 9050, exp: 12522, profit: -3472},
    {year: 2019, monthNumber: 1, rev: 12265, exp: 12752, profit: -487},
    {year: 2018, monthNumber: 2, rev: 9955, exp: 12424, profit: -2469},
    {year: 2018, monthNumber: 2, rev: 13657, exp: 13424, profit: 233},
    {year: 2019, monthNumber: 2, rev: 9050, exp: 12410, profit: -3360},
    {year: 2019, monthNumber: 2, rev: 15045, exp: 13315, profit: 1730}
]

var result={};

function simplearray(obj){
  if(typeof result["rev"]== "undefined")
  {
    result["rev"]={};
  }
  if(typeof result["rev"][obj.year]== "undefined")
  {
    result["rev"][obj.year]=[];
  }      

  if(typeof result["rev"][obj.year][obj.monthNumber]== "undefined")
  {
    result["rev"][obj.year][obj.monthNumber]=0;
  }      
  result["rev"][obj.year][obj.monthNumber]+=obj.rev;

  if(typeof result["exp"]== "undefined")
  {
    result["exp"]={};
  }
  if(typeof result["exp"][obj.year]== "undefined")
  {
    result["exp"][obj.year]=[];
  }      

  if(typeof result["exp"][obj.year][obj.monthNumber]== "undefined")
  {
    result["exp"][obj.year][obj.monthNumber]=0;
  }      
  result["exp"][obj.year][obj.monthNumber]+=obj.exp;
  
  if(typeof result["profit"]== "undefined")
  {
    result["profit"]={};
  }
  if(typeof result["profit"][obj.year]== "undefined")
  {
    result["profit"][obj.year]=[];
  }      

  if(typeof result["profit"][obj.year][obj.monthNumber]== "undefined")
  {
    result["profit"][obj.year][obj.monthNumber]=0;
  }      
  result["profit"][obj.year][obj.monthNumber]+=obj.profit;
}

for (a=0;a<data.length;a++)
{
  simplearray(data[a]);
}   


console.log(result);
console.log(result["profit"][2018][0]);
```

Answer (score -3):

You should check out [OGX.List](https://github.com/globules-io/OGX.JS/wiki/List) (downloadable as stand alone) and use the group function. It groups an array given properties. Since you didn't post any code, I believe you are looking for a lib.

Comment: Could you explain what OGX.List is and show how to use the group function? Link-only answers can become obsolete in the future if their link stops working.